# Datetimepicker component

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td><input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to use datetimepicker in the project, but when I click on the input it shows current date time and not the selector.

Also I am getting:

> Uncaught Error: datetimepicker component should be placed within a
>   non-static positioned container
>       at Y (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
>       at HTMLInputElement.ie (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5237)
>       at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5044)

Comment: `Uncaught Error: datetimepicker component should be placed within a non-static positioned container at Y ` have you tried positioning this inside a div.

Comment: Or you can add `style="position: relative"` to your input.

Comment: @Dapeng114 it has same issue

Comment: `<div><input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' /></div>`, I tried this but has same issue

Comment: Just a small **update**, that how I am using the `input` tag. *I am using it in table*

Comment: @paran it works here https://jsfiddle.net/3yzpkdfu/10/